# Highcharts line and points are shown only on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am trying to show a simple graph using Highcharts. It was working pretty well, but at one point for unknown reasons my line just stopped showing up. The screen seems empty and the points are only visible when mouse hovers over them.

I added a dummy series to check and this is how it looks now:
[image]

The code producing the graph is:

```
$(function () {
            $.get('data/data.txt', function (data) {   
                // Preparing data
                var formatted = []
                var lines = data.split('\n');
                $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
                    var items = line.split('-');

                    formatted.push(
                        [
                            Date.UTC(
                                items[1],
                                items[2],
                                items[3],
                                items[4],
                                items[5],
                                items[6]),
                            parseInt(items[0])
                        ]
                    );
                });
                console.log(formatted)

                // Data prepared, now display it
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime'
                    },
                    series: [
                        {
                            data: formatted,
                            name: "Prize pool"
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Tokyo',
                            data: [[1433620800000,7.0], [1433620822000,6.9], [1433620824000,9.5], [1433620826000,14.5], [1433620828000,18.2]]
                        },
                    ]
                });
            })
        });
```

The data received is correctly formatted, as seen on the screenshot. It has the same structure and very similar values as the 'Tokyo' series. However, only the latter is visible. Changing line widths or colors did nothing. There is no other customization of the graph. What is going on here?

Also the last point of the "hidden" series is completely ignored and never shown.

([video for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoiSwuyeOvE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the graph cannot handle empty data well - in the part where I prepare data to be shown there has to be a handling of empty line (which may occur at the end of the file), and if there is such a line, just ignore it.

Comment: Empty data in Highcharts should be set as "null". If you have extra empty line at the end, then `parseInt(items[0])` will return `NaN`. And of course `Not a Number` can not be displayed on a chart which requires `Numbers` ;) I would rather said that CSV file is corrupted, but just my opinion.